# How can I customize the exponential backoff parameters when reconnecting a grpc-java client?

Tags: grpc-java

Is there any config param available to config the exponential backoff for grpc java?
I want to change the max re-connection times, or backoff delay, or max_backoff.
the version of grpc-java I use is 1.43.2. If any higher version support that, I can upgrade the version of it.

I set the ManagedChannelBuild#setMaxAttemptTimes to 1, but it seems not work for connection retry.

Comment: I don't think there is a configuration to do that. If you are talking about https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html#maxRetryAttempts-int- it is about RPC retries, not connection retries.

Comment: That's right. It is not clear from the original post whether they are looking for connection retries or RPC retries

Comment: The question is about connection retries, not RPC retries.